# What is the best way to strip ammonia from water at a mining site?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Working at a mine and have excess ammonia in the water. Was going to run the water through an ammonia wood chip bio filter, was wondering if this is the best technique or should I approach it from a different way?

Comment: You need an environmental chemist and a lot more information. How much water? What else is in the water? Concentration of ammonia? Where is water going to be discharged? What are appropriate regulations about discharge water?

Comment: In industry , the water would be boiled in a vessel and the vapors treated for specific components. Mine waters are notorious for containing a variety of stuff.

Comment: Interesting question, worrisome context... Sounds a bit like, "hi all, so I'm running this nuclear reactor and I'm wondering what to do about this 'core overheating'  error message that keeps popping up?"